# Analog Meter Image Processing - OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have an image of analog voltmeter:

[image]

I'd like to detect the needle and then find it's direction/angle.

I'm using python and opencv and have tried contours but haven't managed to solve it so far:

```
#I'll insert my code attempts here soon!
```

Comment: You need to show some effort in trying to solve the problem and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried algorithm to find contours and getting center point, but its not getting giving expected output

Comment: if the view is fixed then just scan along the arc in the middle of needle and stop when hit the dark pixels... then use `atan2` ... You can also binarize image and regress line ...

Comment: @TejasSomaiya from a static image of camera stream ?

Answer (score 1):

[Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) should work well for this kind of image.

Needle is the longest and the most powerful straight object, and proper threshold choice could give  good result.

You can also remove some thin segments of scale and make needle thinner with morphological operation [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Simple thresholding to detect all the dark patterns
2. Erase all the small patterns
3. Erase the patterns that touch the border.
4. Geodesic diameter computation in order to detect the longest pattern.
5. PCA in order to determine the orientation.